# SAS conditional IF-THEN statement not working

Tags: if-statement, sas

I am a beginner user of SAS and currently, I'm following one of the Coursera courses. The code given in a lecture doesn't work although I don't see an error. Below the code:

```
PROC IMPORT DATAFILE ='/home/student123/my_courses/nesarc_pds.csv' OUT = data  REPLACE;

LABEL TAB12MDX ="Tobacco Dependance Past 12 Months"
      CHECK321 ="Smoked Cigarettes in Past 12 Months"
      S3AQ3B1 ="Usual Smoking Frequency"
      S3AQ3C1 ="Usual Smoking Quantity";

IF S3AQ3B1=9 THEN S3AQ3B1=.;
IF S3AQ3C1=99 THEN S3AQ3C1=.;
IF CHECK321=1;
IF AGE LE 25;
PROC SORT; BY IDNUM;
PROC FREQ; TABLES TAB12MDX CHECK321 S3AQ3B1 S3AQ3C1 AGE;
RUN;
```

The error I see in a log is:

```
80         IF S3AQ3B1=9 THEN S3AQ3B1=MISSING;
        __
        180
81         IF CHECK321=1;
        __
        180
82         IF AGE LE 25;
        __
        180
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

I use SAS Studio but I don't know does it matter.

Does anyone know where is an error?

Comment: You have a series of data step statements without any actual data step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need a data step or procedure to modify data
2. You should use DATA= to point the procs to the correct data input
3. You only need one RUN but it helps do delineate your code.

   ```
   PROC IMPORT DATAFILE ='/home/student123/my_courses/nesarc_pds.csv' OUT = data  REPLACE;
   RUN;  /*3*/

   Data yourData; /*1*/
   set data;

   LABEL TAB12MDX ="Tobacco Dependance Past 12 Months"
     CHECK321 ="Smoked Cigarettes in Past 12 Months"
     S3AQ3B1 ="Usual Smoking Frequency"
     S3AQ3C1 ="Usual Smoking Quantity";

   IF S3AQ3B1=9 THEN S3AQ3B1=.;
   IF S3AQ3C1=99 THEN S3AQ3C1=.;
   IF CHECK321=1;
   IF AGE LE 25;

   run;  /*3*/

   PROC SORT data=yourData; /*2*/
   BY IDNUM;
   RUN; /*3*/

   PROC FREQ data=yourData; /*2*/
   TABLES TAB12MDX CHECK321 S3AQ3B1 S3AQ3C1 AGE;
   RUN;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run an IF statement or a LABEL statement in the middle of nowhere. They have to be part of a data step (or pat of a proc step that supports those statements).  You need a DATA step.  (Note it is also a good idea to give your datasets more meaningful names than `data`.)

```
PROC IMPORT DATAFILE ='/home/student123/my_courses/nesarc_pds.csv'
  OUT = nesarc_pds REPLACE
;
run;

data youth;
 set nesarc_pds ;
LABEL TAB12MDX ="Tobacco Dependance Past 12 Months"
      CHECK321 ="Smoked Cigarettes in Past 12 Months"
      S3AQ3B1 ="Usual Smoking Frequency"
      S3AQ3C1 ="Usual Smoking Quantity"
;

IF S3AQ3B1=9 THEN S3AQ3B1=.;
IF S3AQ3C1=99 THEN S3AQ3C1=.;
IF CHECK321=1;
IF AGE LE 25;
run;

PROC SORT data=youth; BY IDNUM; 
run;

PROC FREQ data=youth; TABLES TAB12MDX CHECK321 S3AQ3B1 S3AQ3C1 AGE;
RUN;
```